# How to use if condition in string concatenation

Tags: jquery

I want to show button update if `z != null` else will show generate. I have written code but it's lengthy. Can anyone please update my code by using `if` within the concatenation before the `button` so that if `z != null` it will show update else will show generate and then I will not have to write same code again

```js
if (z != null) {
  b += '<div class="col-sm-7 center-div"><h4 class="main-heading">Set report parameters of <strong>' + a + '&nbsp' + c + '</strong> for : <strong>' + data.employeeName + '</strong></h4><form id="report_param" method="post"><div class="panel panel-success"><div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Set Report Parametrs</div>' +
    '<div class="panel-body"><div class="form-group"><label>Year</label><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + c + '" placeholder="Enter Year" readonly /></div>' +
    '<div class="form-group"><label>Month</label><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + a + '" placeholder="Enter Month" readonly /></div>' +
    '<div class="panel-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary update" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Update</button></div></div><input name="test" type="hidden" value="' + data.id + '" data="' + data.id + '"></form></div>';
} else {
  b += '<div class="col-sm-7 center-div"><h4 class="main-heading">Set report parameters of <strong>' + a + '&nbsp' + c + '</strong> for : <strong>' + data.employeeName + '</strong></h4><form id="report_param" method="post"><div class="panel panel-success"><div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Set Report Parametrs</div>' +
    '<div class="panel-body"><div class="form-group"><label>Year</label><input name="yea" type="text" class="form-control" value="' + c + '" placeholder="Enter Year" readonly /></div>' +
    '<div class="form-group"><label>Month</label><input type="text" name="mon" class="form-control" value="' + a + '" placeholder="Enter Month" readonly /></div>' +
    '<div class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success generate"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Generate Report</a></div></div><input name="test" type="hidden" value="' + id + '" data="' + id + '"></form></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to change between the conditions is the button class and text you can create variables to hold the values based on the state of `z`, then concatenate the output in to `b`, like this:

```js
var b = '',
  buttonClass = 'update',
  buttonText = 'Update';

if (z === null) {
  buttonClass = 'generate';
  buttonText = 'Generate Report';
}

b += '<div class="col-sm-7 center-div"><h4 class="main-heading">Set report parameters of <strong>' + a + '&nbsp' + c + '</strong> for : <strong>' + data.employeeName + '</strong></h4><form id="report_param" method="post"><div class="panel panel-success"><div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Set Report Parametrs</div>' +
  '<div class="panel-body"><div class="form-group"><label>Year</label><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + c + '" placeholder="Enter Year" readonly /></div>' +
  '<div class="form-group"><label>Month</label><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + a + '" placeholder="Enter Month" readonly /></div>' +
  '<div class="panel-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary ' + buttonClass + '" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> ' + buttonText + '</button></div></div><input name="test" type="hidden" value="' + data.id + '" data="' + data.id + '"></form></div>';
```

Also note that if you don't need IE support then you can use template literals to make the string concatenation a little less ugly:

```
b += `<div class="col-sm-7 center-div">
  <h4 class="main-heading">
    Set report parameters of 
    <strong>${a}&nbsp${c}</strong> 
    for : 
    <strong>${data.employeeName}</strong>
  </h4>
  <form id="report_param" method="post">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> 
        Set Report Parametrs
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Year</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${c}" placeholder="Enter Year" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Month</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${a}" placeholder="Enter Month" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary ${buttonClass}" type="submit" name="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> 
            ${buttonText}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input name="test" type="hidden" value="${data.id}" data="${data.id}">
  </form>
</div>`;
```

You can also see from the above that you're missing a `</div>` tag.